# Looping through wildcard folders and executing multiple commands in Bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, find

I have a set of commands to change the contents of files called MenuSettings which work fine when directed to a folder.

```
cd /Applications/snowflake/table-updater/Testing/Applications/Salford_100

sed -e '1r MenuSettings.bak' -e '1,2d' MenuSettings.txt >> MenuSettings2.txt
cat MenuSettings2.txt | sed '/^AppName: */{h;s///;x;}; /^\(AppName_.._..:\).*/{s//\1/;G;s/\n/ /;}' >> MenuSettings3.txt
rm -v MenuSettings2.txt
mv -v MenuSettings3.txt MenuSettings.txt
```

However when I try to run them through multiple folders writing this

```
for dir in $(find salford_* -type d);do 

sed -e '1r MenuSettings.bak' -e '1,2d' MenuSettings.txt >> MenuSettings2.txt
cat MenuSettings2.txt | sed '/^AppName: */{h;s///;x;}; /^\(AppName_.._..:\).*/{s//\1/;G;s/\n/ /;}' >> MenuSettings3.txt
rm -v MenuSettings2.txt
mv -v MenuSettings3.txt MenuSettings.txt

done
```

I get the error

```
sed: MenuSettings.txt: No such file or directory
```

Which renders all the following commands ineffective, and I end up with a blank text file on the root of my search. MenuSettings.txt is in every directory with the Salford name. And when i test find to echo what its searching for it shows everything fine. Ive tried a number of find methods but to no avail, can anyone help

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. You never change into that directory, right?

Comment: Thank you, I go into every dir named salford_xxx and edit the file MenuSettings.txt where I need a number of segments replacing, hence sed being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for` does not change directories for you. You should put `${dir}/` in front of your file references,and change some `'` quotes to `"` to allow shell variable interpretation

```
for dir in $(find salford_* -type d);do 

sed -e "1r ${dir}/MenuSettings.bak" -e '1,2d' ${dir}/MenuSettings.txt >> ${dir}/MenuSettings2.txt
sed '/^AppName: */{h;s///;x;}; /^\(AppName_.._..:\).*/{s//\1/;G;s/\n/ /;}' ${dir}/MenuSettings2.txt >> ${dir}/MenuSettings3.txt
rm -v ${dir}/MenuSettings2.txt
mv -v ${dir}/MenuSettings3.txt ${dir}/MenuSettings.txt

done
```

I also removed a "Useless Use of cat". Google that.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Given that I also had subdirectories in the folders, I put -maxdepth parameter in find too.

Comment: Then please Accept my answer, so my reputation will grow and I can end up ruling the world.

Comment: Ive made it so!